# Can you receive a Schengen visa in your new passport, based on a previously issued visa that is still valid?

Tags: visas, schengen, passport-renewals

My old passport with a valid Schengen visa was damaged, I then applied for a new passport.

That Schengen visa was issued by the Spanish embassy. Now I plan to visit Italy, which doesn't like people traveling with two passports according to some rumors I've heard. My question is: can I apply to the Italian embassy to get a new Schengen visa based on the previous one issued by Spain?

Comment: You're not supposed to have two schengen visas at once. There's no rule against using the Schengen visa in an old passport along with a newer passport; in fact there's a court decision explicitly allowing it.  Where do you get the idea that Italy doesn't want you to have two passports?

Comment: thank you for the answer, actually friend of mine told me that based on his experience that Italians were not happy with comming with 2 passports, while they accepted him at the end, he told me that was not smooth process and they asked him to do something like interview in the airport. The rules are different in all 26 countries so it is sure that comming with 2 passports will cause some delay and more questions.

Comment: People always can have multiple passpirts of same type, as long as only one is valid. Of course there are exceptions for US & few other countries. Valid visa in old passport, n a new passport with same bio-data information should be ok.

Comment: @Davinder on the contrary, some countries will issue two passports to people who travel so frequently that they need to travel while their passport is being held for a visa application.  The Netherlands and Germany are two examples I know about.

Comment: Yes @phoog, this is what I meant by "of course there are exceptions for US &....".. India also allows two passports, but both can not be of same type. One can be official, other can be personal.

Answer (score 3):

According to [VFS Global](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/faq.html) (a partner company of many Schengen consulates worldwide):

> **I have a valid Schengen visa but my Indian passport has expired. Can I
>   transfer this visa to my new passport?**
>
> No. If you are holding a valid Schengen visa in an expired Indian
>   passport, you may carry both your expired and new Indian passports
>   together and travel between India and the Schengen countries until the
>   visa expires. You do not need to obtain a new visa.

So the answer is: **no**, you cannot do it.